# Asp.net mvc jquery ajax post returns null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to stackoverflow so sorry for the syntax of posting.
my problem is none values are posted or models not getting any value
here is my controller function :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SendToStoresPost(tempStoreProduct temp)
{
    ViewBag.returenValue = temp.quantity.ToString();
    return Json(ViewBag.returenValue);
}
```

Here is the model:

```
public class tempStoreProduct
{
    public int productid;
    public int quantity;
    public int store;        
}
```

Here is the jquery for ajax post:

```
function send(productid)
{
    var quantity = $('#amount-'+productid).val();
    var store = $('#stores').val();
    var temp = {
        productid: productid,
        quantity: quantity,
        store: store
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "SendToStoresPost", //The url where the server req would we made.
        type: "POST", //The type which you want to use: GET/POST
        data: temp,
        dataType: "JSON", //Return data type (what we expect).
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#ico-'+productid).html('loading');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ico-'+productid).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Stuck here for some time.

Comment: `return Json(ViewBag.returenValue);` Typo! `returnValue` instead of  `returenValue`!

Comment: Yes, this is why you should stay away from the `ViewBag` and `dynamic` types in general!

Comment: it doesnt matter. I dubuged and it seems temp in controller is not getting any value at all.

Comment: The miss type append in both part of the viewbag so everything is fine.

Comment: What if you change the signature of the function for this ? public JsonResult SendToStoresPost(int productid, int quantity, int store)

Comment: here is my debuuggings
[link]http://i.imgur.com/OmHsRT9.png
and i tried using SendToStoresPost(int productid, int quantity, int store) and it works but i am not sure why my way not getting the values

Comment: i tried SendToStoresPost(int productid, int quantity, int store) and it works but not sure why my way not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model properties do not have getters and setters (they are fields!) so the properties cannot be set when posted. Change the model to

```
public class tempStoreProduct
{
  public int productid { get; set; }
  public int quantity { get; set; }
  public int store { get; set; }       
}
```

In addition, if you really have

```
var quantity = $('#amount-'+productid).val();
```

meaning you have controls with `id="amount-1"`, `id="amount-2"` etc, you need to rethink what you doing and learn to construct html based on your model using strongly typed helpers.

Note also assigning a property to view bag in the POST method and then accessing it again is a bit pointless (as is calling `.ToString()`)- it can be just

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SendToStoresPost(tempStoreProduct temp)
{
  return Json(temp.quantity);
}
```

although I assume this is not the real code (why pass a value to the server only to return exactly the same value)

Comment: Is there still a problem?

Comment: oh....I just understood that i have to accept an answer....sorry mate..... thnx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what's wrong is the url in your ajax call. I would suggest you to use the @Url.Action and put it in a javascript variable when you render the view like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var urlSendToStoresPost = '(@Url.Action("SendToStoresPost","ControllerName"))';
</script>
```

I'm not 100% sure of the syntax above.

And later in your ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlSendToStoresPost, //The url where the server req would we made.
    type: "POST", //The type which you want to use: GET/POST
    data: temp,
    dataType: "JSON", //Return data type (what we expect).
    beforeSend:function(){
        $('#ico-'+productid).html('loading');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#ico-'+productid).html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: url is ok.
I dubuged and it seems temp in controller is not getting any value at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
function send(productid)
{
    var quantity = $('#amount-'+productid).val();
    var store = $('#stores').val();
    var temp = {
        productid: productid,
        quantity: quantity,
        store: store
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "SendToStoresPost", //The url where the server req would we made.
        type: "POST", //The type which you want to use: GET/POST
        data: temp,
        dataType: "JSON", //Return data type (what we expect).
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#ico-'+productid).html('loading');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ico-'+productid).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```